# Passing variable upward from makefile targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have several targets in the Makefile. Each target add some values to the makefile variable. For example, CFLAGS.

```
CFLAGS := 1
a: CFLAGS += 2
b: CFLAGS += 3
```

I need to write target "с" which will "see" values assigned in "a" and "b". And which, may be, add some more values.

I tried to do it like this:

```
c: CFLAGS += 4
c: a b
echo ${CFLAGS}
```

Here I planned to see CFLAGS equal to "1 2 3 4" or "1 4 2 3"
But in fact CGLAGS will be equal to:

```
a: 1 4 2
b: 1 4 3
c: 1 4
```

Sample Makefile:

```
CFLAGS := 1
.PHONY: all a b c
all: c

a: CFLAGS += 2
a:
    echo TargetA ${CFLAGS}

b: CFLAGS += 3
b:
    echo TargetB ${CFLAGS}

c: CFLAGS += 4
c: a b
    echo TargetC ${CFLAGS}
```

Any way to do this?

*PS. Some reasoning for ones who want to. 
I have some programs that needs libA. Target "a" that have inclides/libs for libA and is used for these programs.
I have some programs that needs libB.
And I have some programs that needs all: libA, libB and libC.
I want to "reuse" targets "a" and "b" to avoid making assignment duplication.*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other comment, you have the prerequisite relationship backwards to get the behavior you want.

Rather than writing a lot of `call` and `eval` functions, I would prefer to use computed variable names here.  You can do something like this:

```
CFLAGS = 1
CFLAGS_a = 2
CFLAGS_b = 3
CFLAGS_c = 4

all: c
c: a b
a b c:
        @echo '$(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_$@) $(foreach P,$<,$(CFLAGS_$P))'
```

to print the default `CFLAGS`, then the `CFLAGS` for the target, then the `CFLAGS` for each prerequisite.  Of course you'll have to modify this for your specific purposes.

For more information on different types of "metaprogramming" in GNU make, you can read [this set of blog posts](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/).  Start with the first one (which is at the end of that list, unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

From GNU Make's manual section on [*target-specific variables*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html):

> when you define a target-specific variable **that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target**, and all their prerequisites, etc.

In your makefile, `a` and `b` are prerequisites of `c`, so setting `CFLAGS` as a `c`'s *target-specific variable* does have effect also in `a` and `b`. Not the other way around, i.e.: setting `CFLAGS` as an `a` or `b`'s *target-specific variable* has **no** effect in `c` at all, since it is not a prerequisite of any of them.

---

#### Possible alternative

If your motivation for achieving such a thing, is that a target may need an arbitrary combination of any of *libA*, *libB* or *libC*. Then, I would suggest you to define the variables `libA`, `libB`, `libC`, `libAB`, `libAC`, `libBC` and `libABC` that represent the corresponding library combinations and then include one of those variables to the corresponding target as *prerequisite*.

The following makefile may serve as a starting point and clarifies what I want to express as well:

```
.PHONY: all

libsCommon := 1
libsA := $(libsCommon) 2
libsB := $(libsCommon) 3
libsC := $(libsCommon) 4

# $(call include-to,varSrc,varDst)
# for avoiding repetition of libraries
define include-to
    $(eval $2 += $(filter-out $($2),$($1)))
endef

# libsAB
$(call include-to,libsA,libsAB)
$(call include-to,libsB,libsAB)

# libsAC
$(call include-to,libsA,libsAC)
$(call include-to,libsC,libsAC)

# libsBC
$(call include-to,libsB,libsBC)
$(call include-to,libsC,libsBC)

# libsABC (all)
$(call include-to,libsA,libsABC)
$(call include-to,libsB,libsABC)
$(call include-to,libsC,libsAll)

all:
    @echo "libsA:   $(libsA)"
    @echo "libsB:   $(libsB)"
    @echo "libsC:   $(libsC)"
    @echo
    @echo "libsAB:  $(libsAB)"
    @echo "libsAC:  $(libsAC)"
    @echo "libsBC:  $(libsBC)"
    @echo
    @echo "libsABC: $(libsABC)"
```

Running `make` with this makefile produces:

```
libsA:   1 2
libsB:   1 3
libsC:   1 4

libsAB:  1 2 3
libsAC:  1 2 4
libsBC:  1 3 4

libsABC: 1 2 3 4
```

This approach, however, won't scale well when you have many libraries or different possible combinations of them.

In any case, I would strongly recommend that if target `a` does *need* `libA`, then `libA` should be made a *prerequisite* of `a`.